# Laravel 5.1 Join issue while using Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

Here is my Model `Receipe`

```
 public function favorite()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\ReceipeFavorite');
}
```

Here i can able to get the

```
 $userId = 1;
 $favorite = User::find($userId)->favorite;
 return $favorite;
```

Using this i can able to fetch the record with id `user_id` in the `receipe_favorites` table by having this query.

i.e., Record matching for all the coloumns with `user_id` - `1`

```
$favorite = User::find(1)->favorite;
return $favorite;


[{"id":1,"receipe_id":"1","user_id":"1","created_at":"2015-09-15 15:49:12","updated_at":"2015-09-15 15:49:12"},{"id":2,"receipe_id":"2","user_id":"1","created_at":"2015-09-15 15:50:07","updated_at":"2015-09-15 15:50:07"}]
```

Now, I wanted to get the Receipe Name along with the Result.

Here is my Table Structure

Table

```
users
->id

receipe
->id

receipe_favorites
->id
->receipe_id
->user_id
```

**Note :**

I am trying to get the Receipe Id, Receipe Name if the User Id is passed.

Comment: you have three tables right(users,receipe,receipe_favorites)?

Comment: Yes, i do have such 3 tables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following, I had a similar thing to do:

```
public function favorite() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Receipe', 'receipe_favorites', 'user_id', 'receipe_id');
}
```

This is how you define a many-to-many relationship.

Params:

1. Model
2. Pivot table
3. Column to join in current model
4. Column to join model defined in 1)

See more examples [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships)